# Make a Table Sortable using jQuery and a Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, html-table

I am try to make my table sortable. This is what it currently looks like:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover employement_request_panel tablesorter">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
          <th class="center">Name <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></th>
          <th class="center">IQ <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></th>
          <th class="center">Efficiency <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></th>
          <th class="center">Focus <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></th>
          <th class="center">Happiness <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></th>
          <th class="center">Quality <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></th>
          <th class="center">Salery <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
      <%Employe.where(company_id: company.id, request: true).each do |employe|%>
        <tr>
          <td class="center cd-popup-trigger popup1"><i style="color: green;" class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
          <td class="center cd-popup-trigger popup2"><i style="color: red;" class="fa fa-close"></i></td>
          <td class="center js-employee-name"><%=employe.name%></td>
          <td class="center"><%=employe.iq%></td>
          <td class="center"><%=employe.efficiency%></td>
          <td class="center"><%=employe.focus%></td>
          <td class="center"><%=employe.happiness%></td>
          <td class="center"><%=employe.quality.capitalize%></td>
          <td class="center"><%=employe.salery%></td>
          <td class="js-employee-id" style="display:none;"><%=employe.id%></td>
        </tr>
      <%end%>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

But I can not get it to work. I am using [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) to try and sort my table. I am calling `<%= javascript_include_tag('jquery.tablesorter.min.js') %>`, and jQuery but my table are not being not sortable or at least I can not get them to sort on the webapp by clicking the `<th>`'s. I have also added the class `tablesorter` to the table.

Please let me know how to make this work.

Comment: Did you init the plugin to sort your table `$('.tablesorter').tablesorter();` as explained in the documentation? http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Getting-Started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've missed initialization:

```
    $(function() {
        $('.tablesorter').tablesorter();
    });
```

From docs:

> Start by telling tablesorter to sort your table when the document is
>   loaded